# Not able to add 3 JPanels to a main panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I have 3 JPanels and I want to place them all in one JPanel. I used the GridBagLayout for the main panel. But only one panel is getting added. Why might this be?

```
    gblayout=new GridBagLayout();
    gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
    panel1Customizer();
    panel2customizer();
    panel3Customizer();
    setLayout(gblayout);
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gbc.weightx=1;
    gbc.weighty=1;
    gbc.gridheight=GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    add(panel1, gbc);
    add(panel2, gbc);
    gbc.gridwidth=GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    add(panel3, gbc);
```

The customizer methods are ones which add items into these panels.

Comment: This code works fine, the issue is probably elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but I think you need to add a GridBagConstraints to your GridBagLayout. Try look at this site to get the idea on how to work with GridBagLayout: 
[link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1431563&page=26)

Or maybe just use another Layout for your JFrame, maybe BorderLayout or GridLayout to arrange your Panels correctly

Answer (score 1):

You should change gbc.gridx and/or gbc.gridy to be different for each panel

Comment: Actually that's not required, by default the components are appended.

Answer (score 1):

you have to read [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), examples for that [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1460__GridBagLayout.htm) and [GridBagConstraints](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1480__GridBagConstraints.htm), change your `gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;`, if you have problem(s) with `JComponent's Size` then add `setPreferedSize()`; for example

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GBLFillBoth extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public GBLFillBoth() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    GridBagLayout gbag = new GridBagLayout();
    panel.setLayout(gbag);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    JButton btn1 = new JButton("One");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0.5;
    panel.add(btn1, c);
    JButton btn2 = new JButton("Two");
    c.gridx++;
    panel.add(btn2, c);
    //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    JButton btn3 = new JButton("Three");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy++;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    panel.add(btn3, c);
    add(panel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        GBLFillBoth gBLFillBoth = new GBLFillBoth();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a MigLayout instead, the code is much simpler:

```
panel1Customizer();
panel2customizer();
panel3Customizer();
setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, wrap 3"));

add(panel1, "grow");
add(panel2, "grow");
add(panel3, "grow");
```