# JPanel's are not aligning properly

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am trying to align 2 JPanles in a big panel. I am not able to align them properly. I am giving the link to the source code [here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B7OX02zRzeHDYTBlMjNkNGEtNTk5NS00MDgyLWE3ZTgtMzIwN2VmNzE2NTEx&hl=en_US). If you run the source code, you can see that the New Payment Method Radio Button is at the centre and and not just below the payment options panel. How do i get it there. I am extremely sorry for not able to post the screenshot and also for the long code. THANKS A TON IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) if you end up not getting any help here.

Comment: and why new thread, not continue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908535/not-able-to-add-3-jpanels-to-a-main-panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, consider [`BoxLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html), shown below.

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911309 */
public class PaymentPanel extends Box {

    public PaymentPanel() {
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        this.add(new JLabel("Payment Setup"));
        this.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        this.add(new JRadioButton("New payment Method", true));
        this.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        this.add(new JLabel("Invoice"));
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("PaymentPanel");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PaymentPanel().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: there are only one alternative for OP, try - fault - read API - ... forever, as we are all here together/around +1